# How to make the <a = "#"> links into a real functional links to work after using jQuery classRemove and add?

Tags: javascript, jquery

>

I tried this code:

```
$(function(){
$('ul li a').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GG7ZZ/

it works when if i use # as the links

```
<ul>
                <li class="current"><a href="#">menu item1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#aaa">menu item2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#bbb">menu item3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#ccc">menu item4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#ddd">menu item5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#eee">menu item6</a></li>
            </ul>

but when i change those #links into a real link as in #ccc to ccc.php and so on for the rest of the link and click onto the ccc.php for example as below
<ul>
                    <li class="current"><a href="menu1.php">menu item1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="aaa.php">menu item2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="bbb.php">menu item3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ccc.php">menu item4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ddd.php">menu item5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="eee.php">menu item6</a></li>
                </ul>
```

below is my overall code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
            <head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            $(function(){
                    $('ul li a').on('click', function(){
                        $(this).parent().addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
                      });
                    });
                </script>


        </head>
        <body>
           <ul>
                <li class="current"><a href="menu1.php">menu item1</a></li>
                <li><a href="aaa.php">menu item2</a></li>
                <li><a href="bbb.php">menu item3</a></li>
                <li><a href="ccc.php">menu item4</a></li>
                <li><a href="ddd.php">menu item5</a></li>
                <li><a href="eee.php">menu item6</a></li>
            </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

. It will change the highlight from "menu item1" to "menu item4" and after that it will change the highlight the back to "menu item1" instantly. Did I missed out something without knowing it?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are not cancelling the navigation to those URLs then a different page will load. Do you prevent the default action (i.e. navigation)?

Comment: Please include your javascript in your questions. Links to fiddles should only provide a quick testing method, and should not be relied upon to form an important part of your question

Comment: okay i will edit the question with my javascript code inside

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your links change the page, so you have to highlight the right link at page load (because the javascript is "lost" when reaching the new page), meaning you must recognize the current page and add the class to the right link accordingly.

Comment: or ajax could be used to load content depending clicked link but your solution is easier (browser history e.g)

Comment: thank you for your reply. I dont quite understand what your saying. I am sorry I am still a beginner. do you have some sample code for me to refer to. Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you everyone for the guides , I appreciate it very much. It had helped to give me some idea on what to look for. Thank you =)

Answer (score 1):

You should prevent the default behavior of the link as follows

if you want to use the link you put in href then you can use this.href for that matter

```
$(function(){
       $('ul li a').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).parent().addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
       /* you can use this.href that contain the href value */
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. I appreciate it very much =)

Comment: if you think this is a helpful answer, I would appreciate it if you can mark it as such. Thanks